# Qual a sintaxe para fazer busca com array como parâmetro no MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sintaxe

Qual é a sintaxe correta, se é que é possível, para passar um array como parâmetro, utilizando o `FIND_IN_SET` mais ou menos nessa ideia:

```sql
SELECT c.cpf FROM tbl_cliente as c WHERE FIND_IN_SET(array, c.cpf);
```

Comment: A coluna cpf é multivalorada? aparentemente um `IN()` resolve isso.

Comment: não, minha intenção era trazer vários resultados de uma só vez...

Comment: Você pode dar mais detalhes do problema? Ainda parece que `IN` seria mais adequado.

Comment: De onde vem a array? PHP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A função [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) pesquisa um texto (primeiro parâmetro) em uma lista de elementos separados por vírgulas declarados em outra String (segundo parâmetro).

Exemplo:

```sql
mysql> SELECT FIND_IN_SET('b','a,b,c,d');
    -> 2
```

Portanto, se o seu `array` for uma String com elementos separados por vírgulas, use-o da seguinte forma:

```sql
SELECT c.cpf FROM tbl_cliente as c WHERE FIND_IN_SET(c.cpf, array);
```

ou

```sql
SELECT c.cpf FROM tbl_cliente as c WHERE FIND_IN_SET(c.cpf, 'cpf1,cpf2,cpf3');
```

---

Por outro lado, se você tiver uma tabela com CPFs e quiser verificar se o CPF do cliente está nessa tabela, use a cláusula `IN`, que aceita listas de valores separados por vírgulas ou um subselect. Exemplo:

```sql
SELECT c.cpf FROM tbl_cliente as c WHERE c.cpf in ('xxx.xxx.xxx-xx', 'yyy.yyy.yyy-yy')
```

Ou ainda:

```sql
SELECT c.cpf FROM tbl_cliente as c WHERE c.cpf in (select cpf from tbl_outratabela)
```

Comment: Mas qual a sintaxe do array no mysql? BD sempre foi meu fraco...

Comment: @KennyRafael Não existe array no MySQL.

Comment: Vish...como faria então a consulta pra trazer vários CPF´s específicos que eu tenho de uma só vêz?

Comment: @KennyRafael Atualizei a resposta com alguns exemplos. Realmente não existe array em MySQL. Porém você pode simular um usando uma String com os valores separados por vírgula ou a cláusula IN passando um SELECT ou valores distintos.

Comment: Sim sim, eu dormi agora, era só colocar meu valores separados por virgula no segundo parâmetro, era isso mesmo...

Comment: @KennyRafael Neste caso o `IN` é preferível ao `FIND_IN_SET`, acredito que a performance seja melhor.

Answer (score 1):

Uma solução com php seria gerar uma consulta com varias `?` para o `IN()`. e depois passar os cpfs no [execute()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php)do PDO

```php
$sql ='SELECT c.cpf FROM tbl_cliente as c WHERE c.cpf IN(';

$qtd_cpfs = count($cpfs);
$in = str_repeat('?', $qtd_cpfs);
$in = preg_replace('/,$/', '', $in);

$sql .= $in .')';

//depois
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute($cpfs);
```

Comment: Que tal `"... IN('" . implode("'", $cpfs) . "')";`?

Comment: Esta é uma alternativa melhor se os valores estiverem disponíveis num array do PHP ou outra linguagem e a query puder ser manipulada. Mas, se os valores estiverem numa outra tabela, use o `IN` com um *subselect* que será muito mais eficiente.

Comment: @bfavaretto, é necessario passar as `?` e não o valor do cpf pois a consulta é parametrizada.
uma alternativa seria usar, `array_fill()` com `implode()`

Comment: Eu não tinha entendido que era parametrizada. Cadê o bind dos valores?

Comment: @bfavaretto, o `bind` pode ser feito com os metodos `bindValue()`, `bindParam()` e `execute()`.

Comment: Eu sei, é que essa parte está faltando na resposta, ao ponto de ter me levado a pensar que você estava construindo o conteúdo do IN direto.

Comment: A ultima linha é o bind.