# Como selecionar os registros que possuam relação com todos os valores de uma lista?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlfiddle

Tenho a seguinte sql:

```
SELECT DISTINCT cp_pessoa.id, cp_pessoa.nome
   FROM cp_pessoa
LEFT JOIN cp_habilidade_freelancer ON (cp_habilidade_freelancer.id_freelancer = cp_pessoa.id)
LEFT JOIN cp_habilidade ON (cp_habilidade.id = cp_habilidade_freelancer.id_habilidade)
   WHERE cp_habilidade.id = 71 OR cp_habilidade.id = 695
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Eu quero somente as pessoas (cp_pessoa) que tenham todas as habilidades (71, 695).

Pode parecer simples, mas estou com dificuldades.

Exemplos:

Se eu uso OR as seguintes pessoas com as seguintes habilidades (1,2,71) são retornadas (pessoas sem a habilidade 695).
Se eu uso AND as seguintes pessoas com as seguintes habilidades (71, 695) não são retornadas

exemplo: [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd233/1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilize uma subquery na cláusula `WHERE` que contabilize se a pessoa possui as habilitações requeridas.

```sql
SELECT cp_pessoa.id, cp_pessoa.nome
FROM cp_pessoa
WHERE 
      -- Se a pessoa possuir ao menos as habilitações 71 e 695
      (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT cp_habilidade_freelancer.id_habilidade)
       FROM cp_habilidade_freelancer
       WHERE cp_habilidade_freelancer.id_freelancer = cp_pessoa.id
         AND (cp_habilidade_freelancer.id_habilidade = 71 
           OR cp_habilidade_freelancer.id_habilidade = 695)
       ) = 2
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Aproveitando o exemplo do @user4919: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd233/33/0

Comment: funciona, e não precisar usar os JOINs (o que é +1 para mim)

Answer (score 1):

Não posso ter a certeza se isto está correto porque não tenho como testar.

```
SELECT DISTINCT cp_pessoa.id, cp_pessoa.nome
   FROM cp_pessoa
LEFT JOIN cp_habilidade_freelancer ON (cp_habilidade_freelancer.id_freelancer = cp_pessoa.id)
LEFT JOIN cp_habilidade ON (cp_habilidade.id = cp_habilidade_freelancer.id_habilidade)
   WHERE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM cp_habilidade_freelancer WHERE (id_habilidade = 71 OR id_habilidade = 695) AND cp_habilidade_freelancer.id_freelancer = cp_pessoa.id) = 2
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Utilize o [IN()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_in) dessa forma  varios valores podem ser passados por virgula.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT cp_pessoa.id, cp_pessoa.nome
   FROM cp_pessoa
LEFT JOIN cp_habilidade_freelancer ON (cp_habilidade_freelancer.id_freelancer = cp_pessoa.id)
LEFT JOIN cp_habilidade ON (cp_habilidade.id = cp_habilidade_freelancer.id_habilidade)
   WHERE cp_habilidade.id IN(71,695)
LIMIT 0, 10
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, mas com o IN se a pessoa tiver por exemplo as habilidades 71, 695 e 700 não daria certo

Comment: Essa coluna possui varios valores delimitados por alguma caracter como `;`ou `,`

Comment: Você quer as pessoas que tenham 71 e 695 e qualquer outro valor?

Comment: Galera, aqui tem um exemplo melhor: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dd233/1

Comment: O 71 e 695 são exemplos, nesse caso sim, ele tem que ter obrigatoriamente 71 e 695, mas pode ter outros valores também

Comment: Se essa consulta é dinamica, de uma olhada [aqui](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/1788/qual-a-sintaxe-para-fazer-busca-com-array-como-parametro-no-mysql/)

Comment: @user4919 Sugiro editar sua pergunta para incluir esse exemplo no sqlfiddle (assim todos poderão ver - não somente quem estiver lendo esses comentários)

Answer (score 0):

Bem, como tem uma tabela n-m (muitos para muitos) em geral a diferença é que seu campo `WHERE` vai ter ser filtrado por uma `subquery` ou um JOIN complexo. JOINs tendem a ser mais performáticos do que subqueries, mas é questão de testar.

O jeito mais simples, que pode ter performance igual ou até melhor que subquery/joins, em especial para tabelas com MUITOs dados, é você quebrar sua query em duas. Na primeira você acessa a tabela `cp_habilidade_freelancer` e obtem todos os `id_freelancer` que satisfazem sua consulta. Depois, com esses IDs, pode sim usar o `IN()` na query principal.

O jeito de fazer isso em um passo único é aproveitar a query do jeito simples e colocar dentro da query principal. Mas tome cuidado quando sua tabela for grande e não couber na memória.

Answer (score 0):

Creio que utilizando inner join e group by você resolve.Segue:

```
SELECT cp.id, cp.nome
FROM cp_pessoa as cp
inner JOIN  cp_habilidade_freelancer  as chf ON ( chf.id_freelancer=cp.id)
left   JOIN cp_habilidade ch ON (ch.id = chf.id_habilidade) 
and  (chf.id_habilidade =2 and  chf.id_habilidade =1)
group by (nome)
```