# Ler coluna do phpMyAdmin com vários registros

Tags: php, mysql

Possuo uma tabela no phpMyAdmin com um campo que armazena vários valores, a coluna está nomeada como id_subfiltro, preciso ler cada valor desse, pois os mesmos são id´s que estão relacionados a outra tabela o campo é um varchar.

A tabela é essa, o campo que preciso ler é o que está marcado, vejam:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consegui achar nada relacionado pelas pesquisas que fiz.

Comment: Você quer usar esses IDs para fazer um JOIN com outra tabela, é isso?

Comment: Isso mesmo @bfavaretto, preciso separa-los para usar no relacionamento.

Comment: O bom era não ter essa coluna multivalorada se não puder transforma-la numa nova tabela, talvez essa resposta possa ajudar: [Qual a sintaxe para fazer busca com array como parâmetro no MySQL?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1788/91)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se o objetivo é fazer um `JOIN` com outra tabela, o MySQL oferece um atalho que é a função [`FIND_IN_SET`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set). Porém ela tem problemas de performance, o correto mesmo seria modelar o banco de outra maneira e usar uma tabela de relacionamento, como já sugerido na resposta do Alfredo Silveira e no comentário do rray.

Para constar, segue um exemplo de **gambiarra** com o `FIND_IN_SET`:

```
SELECT tabela1.*
FROM tabela1
    INNER JOIN tabela2
    ON FIND_IN_SET(tabela2.id, tabela1.id_subfiltro) > 0
```

Comment: A sua solução de POG me ajudou muito meu caro, agradeço a atenção.

Comment: + 1 por admitir a gambiarra kkkkkk

Answer (score 3):

Recomendo que faça uma melhor modelagem do banco, criando uma tabela relacional para esse caso.

Como por exemplo, uma tabela entre equipamentos e trabalhadores ambas possuem um identificador **ID**, para relacionar de maneira adequada com uma cardinalidade *N* pra *N* de relacionamento, ficaria bom criar uma tabela `equipamentos_trabalhadores` onde existiria o `id_equipamento` e o `id_trabalhor`, isso poderia relacionar *N* registros, podendo ser consultado apenas por `id_equipamento` ou `id_trabalhor`, tornando assim o acesso mais fácil e mais rápido.

Mas caso queira continuar com essa modelagem, pode-se trazer todos os dados para a programação, ou para a consulta, e utilizar métodos de expressão regular que seu uso varia dependendo da linguagem de programação desejada.

Por usar o PhpMyAdmin imagino que deva usar o PHP, por isso colocarei uma referencia de expressão regular em PHP, mas caso não seja essa função está disponível em todas as linguagens, segue referencia:

http://www.devmedia.com.br/expressoes-regulares-em-php/25076

Com esse método se consegue pegar partículas de um determinado texto, podendo assim separar os *ids* que deseja, porém, esse jeito não é muito adequado para esse tratamento.

Comment: Se for pra resolver no PHP, um `explode` resolveria, nem precisa de regex... Mas concordo com você que o correto é modelar o banco de outra maneira.

Comment: Sim, eu não entendendo muito de PHP, tentei passar um método genérico

Comment: Sem problemas, desculpe ficar te enchendo...

Comment: Que nada, pelo contrario, agradeço pela ajuda