# criar variável a partir do resultado de uma consulta e usar essa variável em outra consulta

Tags: php, mysql

é o seguinte, to fazendo uma consulta no banco de dados com php! O codigo que uso é o seguinte:

```
<?php

$rs = $pdo->query(" SELECT * FROM licitacoes WHERE ID_USER = '$IDLOGADO' ")->fetchAll();

if(!$rs){ print_r($pdo->errorInfo()); }foreach ($rs as $row){

    echo $row['ID_LICITI'] ;}

?>
```

O resultado dessa consulta é: `2 | 0`

Quero então transformar esse resultando em uma variável para que eu possa usar ele em outra consulta! Algo tipo assim

```
<?php

$rs = $pdo->query(" SELECT * FROM outratabela WHERE ID_LICITI = $resultado or  ID_LICITI = $resultado")->fetchAll();

if(!$rs){ print_r($pdo->errorInfo()); }foreach ($rs as $row){

    echo $row['ID_LICITI'] ;}

?>
```

Como pode obervação quero que crie um `Where` no primeiro $resultado e caso venha ter mais de um resultado quero que adicione os `OR` de acordo com os resultados.

Quero fazer isso pois os resultados da primeira consulta são parâmetros para filtrar os resultados da segunda consulta, porem esse "filtro" sera dado pela mesma quantia de resultados da consulta anterior, que será no máximo 9 resultados.

Claro que isso foi o modo que pensei (e nao ta dando muito certo, pois não sei como fazer, to perdido aqui), porem se como fazer de outra maneira (uma mais facial) eu agradeço

Answer (score 2):

A maneira mais simples, seria usar um [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) para transformar o array da primeira consulta em uma string separada por virgulas e jogar isso na clásula `IN` do sql.

O problema é que variáveis passadas diretamente na instrução sql estão sujeitas a ataques de sql injection, como está usando o PDO o ideal seria utlizar prepared statements. A lógica para resolver esse problema pode ser vista [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/33528/91) e [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1794/91)

```
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM outratabela WHERE ID_LICITI '; //segunda consulta.
if(count($rs) > 1){

   $sql .= 'IN('. implode($rs, ',') .')';

   $itens = $pdo->query($sql)->fetchAll();
}
```

Comment: faltou concatenar a string -> $sql .= 'IN(

Comment: @AdirKuhn, obrigado faltou mesmo o ponto hehe :)