# Como encontrar um item em um campo separado por virgulas?

Tags: php, mysql, array, query

Tenho um campo em uma tabela com dados separados por vírgula:
`id_regioes: 1,2,3,4,5,6`.

Quando faço a *query* `` "SELECT * FROM `tb_operadora` WHERE `id_regioes` = 1" ``, ou `"= 6"` retorna ok, mas não quando são em 2,3,4,5. Mesmo usando `LIKE`. Acho que por que eu preciso montar um *array* antes da *query*.
Como faço para encontrar os dados em PHP + MySQL?

Quando faço a busca nesse campo separado por vírgulas, ele só encontra itens que se encaixem no primeiro e/ou no último registro do campo.

Comment: Pode ajudar http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/1788

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer uso da função [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT *
FROM `tb_operadora`
WHERE FIND_IN_SET( 3, `id_regioes` )
```

O que é efeito é localizar o valor do primeiro parâmetro num conjunto definido no segundo parâmetro.

Comment: Vi agora o link colocado pelo @rray nos comentários que efetivamente responde à pergunta com a solução adequada.

Comment: OK, vou tentar essa solução, depois aviso se funcionou para o que eu quero! Obrigado por enquanto!

Comment: Perfeito! Muito obrigado!