# como exibir postagens relacionada atraves de tags php

Tags: php, banco-de-dados

Tenho um sistema postagem onde o usuario faz uma postagem com os seguintes campos: titulo, descrição, tags(separada por virgula) como eu poderia fazer uma consuta na tabela atraves das tags e exibir as postagens relacinadas?

Comment: Posta o esquema de banco de dados e o código PHP

Comment: tabela noticias

Comment: Poste a sql de criação das tabelas no corpo da pergunta e o código php relacionado

Comment: Talvez ajude, [Qual a sintaxe para fazer busca com array como parâmetro no MySQL?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1792/91)

Comment: SELECT *, MATCH(titulo, descrição) AGAINST('$itulo') AS score
FROM postagens 
WHERE MATCH(titulo, descrição) AGAINST('$titulo') 
ORDER BY score DESC LIMIT 5 mais ou menos isso?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**1º caso:** Pode fazer algo como isso:

```
SELECT *.noticias,
         noticias.tags
FROM     noticias
WHERE    noticias.tags IN('mysql', 'php', 'jquery')   
ORDER BY data_noticias DESC, noticias.tags;
```

Posso claro:

> Selecione tudo da tabela noticias e o valor do campo tags da tabela noticias onde o valor do campo tags está na lista (valor 1, valor 2, valor 3) e
>   ordene por data decrescente e pela tags de forma ascendente.

**2º caso:** Você pode fazer isso de forma relacional também, com três tabelas, você cadastra as tags dentro de uma tabela e o relacionamento entre as tabelas em outra tabela, relacionando tudo pela chave estrangeira. Digamos que você tem três tabelas:

**1ª tabela - noticias:**

```
+----------------------------------------------+
| id_noticia |   titulo   |     descricao      |
+----------------------------------------------+
|      1     | exemplo 1  | lorem inpsun dolor |
+----------------------------------------------+
|      2     | exemplo 2  | lorem inpsun dolor |
+----------------------------------------------+
```

**2ª tabela - tabela_tags:**
Crie uma tabela para cadastrar todas as suas tags

```
+----------------+
| id_tag |  tag  |
+----------------+
|   1    | tag1  |
+----------------+
|   2    | tag2  |
+----------------+
|   3    | tag3  |
+----------------+
```

**3ª tabela - tabela_rel_tags:**
"id_fk_noticia" seria a "id_noticia" (da tabela noticias) 
e "id_fk_tag" seria a id_tag da tabela tabela_tags.

```
+--------------------------------------+
| id_rel | id_fk_tag |  id_fk_noticia  |
+--------------------------------------+
|   1    |     1     |        1        |
+--------------------------------------+
|   2    |     2     |        2        |
+--------------------------------------+
|   3    |     3     |        2        |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Então, você coleta as tags a partir da tabela relacional, Exemplo:

```
//declara o tipo: array
$select= array();
//traz do banco as tags consultadas
$tags = array(
            1 => 'tag1',
            2 => 'tag2',
            3 => 'tag3'
            );
//inicia o array de seleções
$select[] = "SELECT *.noticias";

//faz o loop nas tags consultadas
foreach ($tags as $id_tag => $tag) {
   //na query você verifica se a id da tabela tag consta na sua tabela relacional, se existir você cria um alias com o nome da tag e traz a id no campo 
   $select[] = "IF(tabela_rel_tags.tags = '$id_tag', tabela_rel_tags.tags, null) as '$tag'";
}
//monta a string da sua query separando-a por vírgulas
$sql = implode(", ", $select);
//concatena o resto da sua query que irá relacionar as tabelas
$sql .= "
FROM   noticias
INNER  JOIN tabela_rel_tags ON(tabela_rel_tags.id_fk_noticias = noticias.id_noticia) 
INNER  JOIN tabela_tags ON (tabela_tags.id_tag = tabela_rel_tags.id_tag)
WHERE  tabela_tags.tags IN (".implode(",", $tags).")  
ORDER  BY data_noticias DESC, noticias.tags; ";
```

Comment: os posts seria o que vc pode me explicar melhor o codigo?

Comment: so mais mais uma pergunta como eu vou saber os valores do campo tags para fazer a consuta?

Comment: No 1º caso, você teria que fazer uma tag somente para cada notícia.
No 2º caso, você pode ter mais de uma tag relacionada.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *.posts,
         posts.tags
FROM     posts
WHERE    posts.tags IN('mysql', 'php', 'jquery')   
ORDER BY date_post DESC, posts.tags;
```

O `select*.posts`: seria a tabela das suas postagens e quando aparece posts.tags seria relacionar o video e as tags.