# explode() direto no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Tenho uma coluna chamada `relacionados` na tabela `produtos` e lá tem algumas ID's de alguns itens da tabela `produtos`. Precisava fazer um **explode()** ou algo do tipo na tabela `produtos` e seleciona todos os produtos com as ID's que estão nessa tabela `relacionados`. Teria alguma possibilidade ? As ID's são separados por **,** (virgulas).

```
Tabela = produtos
Coluna = relacionados
```

Mas não preciso retornar quantas ID's tem. O que preciso é retornar como se fosse vários `SELECTS` com as ID's que estão na coluna `relacionados`. Como por exemplo, na coluna `relacionados` tenho assim: `2,3,5,10` então precisava fazer algo tipo assim:

```
SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id = 2
SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id = 3
SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id = 5
SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE id = 10
```

Comment: É só para comparar um valor? [essa resposta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/1792/91) resolve?

Comment: e como você decide qual linha da "relacionados" vai pegar? Se for uma segunda query, é exatamente o que já foi respondido. Supondo que a coluna esteja em $relacionado `"SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE FIND_IN_SET( id, '$relacionado');"`

Answer (score 4):

> Estou esperando a comunidade decidir para ver se é duplicata da que o @rray recomendou.

Se os valores forem separados por vírgula e quiser achar um deles:

```
SELECT * WHERE FIND_IN_SET( 'b','a,b,c,d');
```

No seu caso pode ser usado assim:

```
SELECT * WHERE FIND_IN_SET( 'b', valores );
```

Se forem separados por outro caractere, tem <strike>uma gambiarra</strike> um reparo técnico:

```
SELECT * WHERE FIND_IN_SET( 'b', REPLACE( coluna, '|', ',' ) );
```

Comment: Queria fazer um `SELECT` que faça tipo vários SELECTS com as ID's que estão na coluna ``relacionados`` que estão separados por "," (virgulas). Minha ideia é como se fosse fazer **"SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE codigo_chave = 3"**, **"SELECT * FROM produtos WHERE codigo_chave = 2"**, etc.. Sendo que na coluna relacionados do produto com o codigo_chave é 1 por exemplo e na coluna `relacionados` tem o código chave `2,3`

Comment: salvou!!! valeeeuuu